# Issue with Kafka Broker - UnknownServerException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, reactive-kafka

Our application uses `springBootVersion = 2.0.4.RELEASE` along with `compile('io.projectreactor.kafka:reactor-kafka:1.0.1.RELEASE')` dependency.

The Kafka Broker that we have is at version `1.0.1`.

Intermittently when we send the messages onto Kafka by creating `reactor.kafka.sender.SenderRecord` and in response of Kafka when look for `reactor.kafka.sender.SenderResult.exception()` we have

`java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnknownServerException: The server experienced an unexpected error when processing the request` populated in the exception.

Upon retrying couple of times, the messages get through successfully.

On the broker logs the below error is being printed multiple times without any stacktrace

`[2019-02-08 15:43:07,501] ERROR [ReplicaManager broker=3] Error processing append operation on partition price-promotions-local-event-0 (kafka.server.ReplicaManager)`

where `price-promotions-local-event` is our topic.

I have looked online but there is no definitive resolution or ways to triage this issue, many thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: do you use snappy, by any chance ?

Comment: @AsierAranbarri, yes the compile time dependency on `reactor-kafka:1.0.1.RELEASE` is dependent on `snappy-java:1.1.4` please see the below

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

+--- io.projectreactor.kafka:reactor-kafka:1.0.1.RELEASE
|    +--- io.projectreactor:reactor-core:3.1.8.RELEASE (*)
|    \--- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:1.0.2
|         +--- org.lz4:lz4-java:1.4
|         +--- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:1.1.4
|         \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25

Comment: take a look here, may be helpful: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3764 and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3789

Comment: @AsierAranbarri from what I understood Kafka 0.10.0 was suffering from "Error processing append operation on partition" caused by a bug in snappy-java where parsing the MAGIC HEADER was being handled incorrectly.

snappy-java-1.1.2.6 was released to fix this issue.

The latest version of reactor-kafka is 1.1.0.RELEASE that depends on kafka-clients 2.0.0 which in turn depends on snappy-java 1.1.7.1 
so an upgrade of our reactor-kafka dependency could resolve the issue? or will there be any other approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On further investigating we could get the stacktrace on broker logs as

```
ERROR [ReplicaManager broker=1] Error processing append operation on partition price-promotions-local-event-0 (kafka.server.ReplicaManager)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Magic v1 does not support record headers
    at org.apache.kafka.common.record.MemoryRecordsBuilder.appendWithOffset(MemoryRecordsBuilder.java:403)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.record.MemoryRecordsBuilder.appendWithOffset(MemoryRecordsBuilder.java:442)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.record.MemoryRecordsBuilder.appendWithOffset(MemoryRecordsBuilder.java:595)
    at kafka.log.LogValidator$.$anonfun$convertAndAssignOffsetsNonCompressed$2(LogValidator.scala:138)
    at kafka.log.LogValidator$.$anonfun$convertAndAssignOffsetsNonCompressed$2$adapted(LogValidator.scala:136)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:929)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:929)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1417)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:71)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:70)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at kafka.log.LogValidator$.$anonfun$convertAndAssignOffsetsNonCompressed$1(LogValidator.scala:136)
    at kafka.log.LogValidator$.$anonfun$convertAndAssignOffsetsNonCompressed$1$adapted(LogValidator.scala:133)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:929)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:929)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1417)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:71)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:70)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at kafka.log.LogValidator$.convertAndAssignOffsetsNonCompressed(LogValidator.scala:133)
    at kafka.log.LogValidator$.validateMessagesAndAssignOffsets(LogValidator.scala:64)
    at kafka.log.Log.liftedTree1$1(Log.scala:654)
    at kafka.log.Log.$anonfun$append$2(Log.scala:642)
    at kafka.log.Log.maybeHandleIOException(Log.scala:1669)
    at kafka.log.Log.append(Log.scala:624)
    at kafka.log.Log.appendAsLeader(Log.scala:597)
    at kafka.cluster.Partition.$anonfun$appendRecordsToLeader$1(Partition.scala:499)
    at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inLock(CoreUtils.scala:217)
    at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inReadLock(CoreUtils.scala:223)
    at kafka.cluster.Partition.appendRecordsToLeader(Partition.scala:487)
    at kafka.server.ReplicaManager.$anonfun$appendToLocalLog$2(ReplicaManager.scala:724)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.$anonfun$foreach$1(HashMap.scala:138)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:236)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable.foreachEntry$(HashTable.scala:229)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:138)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:227)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
    at kafka.server.ReplicaManager.appendToLocalLog(ReplicaManager.scala:708)
    at kafka.server.ReplicaManager.appendRecords(ReplicaManager.scala:459)
    at kafka.server.KafkaApis.handleProduceRequest(KafkaApis.scala:465)
    at kafka.server.KafkaApis.handle(KafkaApis.scala:98)
    at kafka.server.KafkaRequestHandler.run(KafkaRequestHandler.scala:65)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

From the class file `MemoryRecordsBuilder` available in `org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:1.0.2` we have the below from where this `IllegalArgumentException` is being thrown.

```
if (magic < RecordBatch.MAGIC_VALUE_V2 && headers != null && headers.length > 0)
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Magic v" + magic + " does not support record headers");
```

So, there were headers being set in the `ProducerRecord` which was causing the issue, upon printing the `ProducerRecord` we discovered that the headers were added by AppDynamics -- a “singularityheader” is getting added to Kafka Produced record.

```
c.t.a.p.i.m.i.KafkaProducerInterceptor   : The kafka Interceptor ProducerRecord header:: RecordHeader(key = singularityheader, value = [110, 111, 116, 120, 100, 101, 116, 101, 99, 116, 61, 116, 114, 117, 101, 42, 99, 116, 114, 108, 103, 117, 105, 100, 61, 49, 53, 53, 49, 51, 55, 51, 54, 57, 49, 42, 97, 112, 112, 73, 100, 61, 55, 49, 48, 51, 50, 42, 110, 111, 100, 101, 105, 100, 61, 49, 51, 53, 55, 53, 51, 53])
```

more reading https://developer.ibm.com/messaging/2018/07/10/additional-rfh-header-added-appdynamics-monitor-agent-tool/

so we have explicitly set the headers to null in the interceptor and this has resolved the issue.

Comment: Where did you find this stack trace?

Comment: @AndrasHatvani you can check the broker logs after enabling them if not done already in `server.log` file under logs directory.... please see here for more info https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cloud-paks/cp-biz-automation/19.0.x?topic=emitter-enabling-kafka-broker-trace

Comment: Thanks, apparently we don't persist the logs in a file, but only print them to standard out in Kubernetes pods which then will be collected by grafana & co.